# Play 2.4.x Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:443 SocketException: Permission denied

Tags: https, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt-native-packager

I installed my play app(Activoids) via `yum install` packaged by sbt native packager as RPM. While starting the play app as service on ec2-user I get exception as `Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:443`. I use self-signed certificate.

I tried launching via `sudo env` before packaging. It works but learnt that it is not the right way.

Config

```
   -DapplyEvolutions.default=false
    -Dhttp.port=disabled
    -Dhttps.port=443
    -Dhttps.keyStore=conf/keystore.jks
    -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=
```

Logs

```
[info] >>> binding text -> java.lang.String
[info] >>> binding bool -> Boolean
[info] - play.api.Play - Application started (Prod)
Oops, cannot start the server.
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:443
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$2.apply(NettyServer.scala:141)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$2.apply(NettyServer.scala:138)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.scala:138)
    at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:200)
    at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:199)
    at play.core.server.ServerProvider$class.createServer(ServerProvider.scala:24)
    at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:199)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:58)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
```

My question is how to overcome this issue.

Env: Scala, Play 2.4.x, AWS linux AMI & SBT native packager

Comment: **443** is a root port, i.e. requires admin privs, so my first guess is that you don't start the server as root. Can you run it again with `sudo`?

Comment: Thanks Jacek, as adviced I tried to start the service as "sudo service Activoids start" I still get the same error. as experimental I tried   using daemonUser in Linux := "root"  in my build.sbt. It started. My app is installed under /opt/Activoids  with (   drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Dec 20 03:27 Activoids )

Comment: [gabriel chavarria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10232154) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66035161) saying "have you checked if your EC2 instance has inbound por 443 port open? and because the 443 port is for https, have you config the certificate in AWS?"

Comment: Buddy, the Question was asked  5 years ago. I am done with that company.